# How to save a run-time-created bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

In my application a user can upload some pictures and for database size limits I would like to merge these images to create only one image, I do that with:

```
private Bitmap combineImageIntoOne(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap) {
            int w = 0, h = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {
                    if (i < bitmap.size() - 1) {
                            w = bitmap.get(i).getWidth() > bitmap.get(i + 1).getWidth() ? bitmap.get(i).getWidth() : bitmap.get(i + 1).getWidth();
                    }
                    h += bitmap.get(i).getHeight();
            }

            Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(temp);
            int top = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("HTML", "Combine: "+i+"/"+bitmap.size()+1);

                    top = (i == 0 ? 0 : top+bitmap.get(i).getHeight());
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(i), 0f, top, null);
            }
            return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bitmap.compress` is the method you are looking for - it allows you to save `Bitmap` to any `OutputStream` you want.

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(someFile));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But then where do I can find the picture?

Comment: In my example it is in `someFile` (which is `java.io.File`)

Comment: Location is specified by `someFile`, as I just said.